# Integrate Keycloak Admin Client 3.1.0.Final with Spring Boot 1.5.1

Tags: spring-boot, resteasy, keycloak

I'm trying to integrate KeyCloak Admin Client with Spring Boot

But there is an exception is thrown when I was trying to create a new account:

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse
```

So I tried to explicitly register Jackson Provider for KeyCloak like this:

```
            KeycloakBuilder
            .builder()
            .serverUrl(SERVER_URL)
            .realm(REALM)
            .username(USERNAME)
            .password(PASSWORD)
            .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                  .providerFactory(factory.register(ResteasyJackson2Provider.class))
                    .connectionPoolSize(10)
                    .build())
            .build();
```

But I'm unable to import `ResteasyJackson2Provider.class`

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Btw, if I use `resteasy-jackson-provider`, I got this exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access_token" (Class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse$InputStreamWrapper@7cc842b0; line: 1, column: 18] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse["access_token"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while, I figured out the solution to this problem:

Firstly, I tested it out with the standalone project (empty maven project), the problem still occurs because of `resteasy-jackson-provider`. It should be `resteasy-jackson2-provider` (note that its resteasy-**jackson2**-provider)

For now, I was known that the problem somehow comes from Spring Boot, RESTeasy. And finally, I come up with this working **pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

One more thing to note is, you should use the **admin-cli** client in your Keycloak, because by default, it has **Direct Access Grants Enabled** on

Btw, this is the Java configuration:

```
            KeycloakBuilder
            .builder()
            .serverUrl("localhost:8080/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .username("YOUR_USERNAME")
            .password("YOUR_PASSWORD")
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .build();
```

Working example: https://github.com/phuongtailtranminh/Keycloak-Admin-Client-Spring-Boot-Demo

Comment: admin-cli it's already configured well, but you can use whatever client, as long as the authentication flow is matching on both parts!